# Plotting several images in the same plot

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to plot small images on a larger plot... Actually its isomap algorithm, I got many points, now each point correspond to some image, I know which image is it... The porblem is how to load that image and plot on the graph? 
One more thing I have to plot both image and the points, so, basically the images will overlap the points.
Certainly, the type of image given [here](http://web.mit.edu/cocosci/isomap/handfig.html)

Answer (score 6):

Something like this should get you started. You can use the low-level version of the `image` function to draw onto a set of axes.

```
% Define some random data
N = 5;
x = rand(N, 1);
y = rand(N, 1);

% Load an image
rgb = imread('ngc6543a.jpg');

% Draw a scatter plot
scatter(x, y);
axis([0 1 0 1]);

% Offsets of image from associated point
dx = 0.02;
dy = 0.02;

width = 0.1;
height = size(rgb, 1) / size(rgb, 2) * width;

for i = 1:N
  image('CData', rgb,...
        'XData', [x(i)-dx x(i)-(dx+width)],...
        'YData', [y(i)-dy y(i)-(dy+height)]);
end
```

[image]